# How can I remove first loading circle div (id="nuxt-loading") in Nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js

I copied some files from here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/custom-loading?from-embed

- pages/about.vue
- pages/index.vue
- components/loading.vue

And setted nuxt.config.js. See below.

**project/components/loading.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="loading" id="loader">
    <p>asdasdasd...</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            loading: false
        }),
        methods: {
            start () {
                this.loading = true
            },
            finish () {
                this.loading = false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**project/nuxt.config.js**

```js
{
    // ...
    loading: '~/components/loading',
    // ...
}
```

Next step, I setted setTimeout ms from 1000 to 60000 for test. I got another loading page on first load, not **components/loading.vue**. The second and the other loading was good, but not the first.

I saw after F12 and I found it in project.
**project/.nuxt/loading.html**

```html
<style>
#nuxt-loading {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  animation: nuxtLoadingIn 10s ease;
  -webkit-animation: nuxtLoadingIn 10s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes nuxtLoadingIn {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes nuxtLoadingIn {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#nuxt-loading>div,
#nuxt-loading>div:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
}

#nuxt-loading>div {
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  border: .5rem solid #F5F5F5;
  border-left: .5rem solid #D3D3D3;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation: nuxtLoading 1.1s infinite linear;
  animation: nuxtLoading 1.1s infinite linear;
}

#nuxt-loading.error>div {
  border-left: .5rem solid #ff4500;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes nuxtLoading {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes nuxtLoading {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
</style>

<script>
window.addEventListener('error', function () {
  var e = document.getElementById('nuxt-loading');
  if (e) {
    e.className += ' error';
  }
});
</script>

<div id="nuxt-loading" aria-live="polite" role="status"><div>Loading...</div></div>

<!-- https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders -->
```

So my question. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure the default loading screen for Nuxt using the `loadingIndicator` option in your `nuxt.config.js` file.

Documentation here: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading-indicator

Example:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
loadingIndicator: {
  name: 'circle',
  color: '#3B8070',
  background: 'white'
}
```

The `loadingIndicator` option can also be a string pointing to a custom HTML template (if you don't want to use Nuxt's built-in loaders).

```js
// nuxt.config.js
loadingIndicator: '~/loading.html'
```